# How to write intent of an agent where date is essential parameter?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am new to DialogFlow and developing an agent which gives year wise information.

The intent named as YearData and following phrases are used for training 
         1. "year wise report" 
         2.  "Annual report of 2017"
         3.  "where i can find annual report"

and i have set parameter name date-period as required now when i am giving the year 9999 its showing the same response for 2017 or 2018. I want to limit it to a valid date

When a user give invalid date ..the system should prompt that date is not valid or not in the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fulfillment webhook, check to make sure it is a valid date and, if not, send back a message saying so.